# Показать картинку только после загрузки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Сделан лендинг, который тягает картинки со стороннего сервера (где они формируются динамически, исходя из параметров)
условно говоря задал фамилию и имя, получил персональную открытку.

Только генерация этой картинки занимает большое время.
Как получить некую прелоад картинку, которую заменить JS-скриптом на нужную..

Условно говоря в слайдере крутятся 4 картинки, каждая из которых поэтапно заменяется на сгенерированную на сервере, когда она готова.

Я готов сначала подсунуть картинку в размер с "тестовыми данными", которые на лету заменятся персональными.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это надо делать lazy-loading, в интернете много информации.

Вот простой пример:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  const images = document.querySelectorAll('.lazy-image')

  for (let image of images)
    if (image.dataset.src)
      image.src = image.dataset.src
})
```

```css
.lazy-image {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<img 
  src="https://picsum.photos/50/50/?random=1" 
  data-src="https://picsum.photos/190/190?random=1" 
  class="lazy-image" 
/>
<img 
  src="https://picsum.photos/50/50/" 
  data-src="https://picsum.photos/190/190/" 
  class="lazy-image"
/>
```

Суть в том что картинкам ставится изначально в src url маленькие картинки, они подгружаются и сразу отображаются, а потом src меняется на главную картинку, маленькая не пропадает пока не загрузиться большая.